# Verify ownership web master central problem with authentication google account redirect

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-datastore, google-authentication, google-account

I'm trying to verify my site with a domain in appspot.com but i use
the authentication whit google account when the web master central try
to verify appears an error

```
  "We weren't able to verify your site: "
```

cuz . Your verification file redirects to a disallowed location , the
redirect goes to https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?... so
how can i verify my site ?, can i disabled de athentication? or what
is the best way ... I hope some one can help me. Thx.

Comment: Please don't talk in txt-speak, high quality readable questions get more answers on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a custom handler for that file ([Python](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Pattern_Handlers)|[Java](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files)), and make sure you are *not* requiring login to view that url ([Python](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status)|[Java](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Security_and_Authentication)).